# Why is HashSet maintaining natural/ alphabetical order?

Tags: java, hashset

When I run below code it is always giving the o/p in natural/ alphabetical order. As per I know `HashSet` doesn't sort the entries. I know that `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap` and not `LinkedHashMap`. I tried to explore the source code of `HashSet` and `HashMap` but couldn't find the code for this behavior.

From the source code there is below constructor in `HashSet` class:

```
HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean dummy) {
        map = new LinkedHashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }
```

which uses `LinkedHashMap`. If I had used this constructor I would think this is the reason for this behavior but I'm not using this constructor.

Could someone please explain the reason/ code for this behavior?

Here's my simple code:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

        mySet.add("D");
        mySet.add("B");
        mySet.add("1");
        mySet.add("E");
        mySet.add("A");
        mySet.add("F");

        mySet.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

***OP:***

```
1
A
B
D
E
F
```

Comment: Coincidence, effectively - quite possibly linked to those hash codes being in order and within a small range. Try adding "BX" into the mix, for example...

Comment: The set order is affected by the hash code; the hash code is affected by the value; the values are in order; this can lead to the set elements being in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coincidence because the default HashSet is bigger than the range of the hashes and there are no collisions, and the hashes for the Strings end up being in alphabetical order.

This is the code for String.hashCode:

```
   public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0) {
            int off = offset;
            char val[] = value;
            int len = count;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

As you can see, the hash for one-character string ends up just being the character value.

The [default capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet()) of HashSet is 16, which means all your values end up in the bucket `char value % 16` which turns out to be alphabetical order for your example. Try with "2" instead of "1", for example, this should end up after "A". Even if you swap "A" and "1" this should swap them in the output too. See [Ascii table](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange).

Comment: Well for IP order `DEAFB2` OP is `AB2DEF` and for `D2EAFB` OP is `A2BDEF`

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Yes because B and 2 hit the same bucket, as are A and 1 (I was wrong that there are no collisions).

Answer (score 1):

From [Java 8 Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So in other words, you cannot rely on the order of the elements in a HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and you would see that the hashcode of the added elements are in a ascending order :

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

mySet.add("D");
mySet.add("B");
mySet.add("1");
mySet.add("E");
mySet.add("A");
mySet.add("F");

mySet.stream()
     .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " : " + x.hashCode()));

System.out.println(mySet);
```

> 1 : 49
>
> A : 65
>
> B : 66
>
> D : 68
>
> E : 69
>
> F : 70
>
> [1, A, B, D, E, F]

Here you used a very particular example : you added only `String`s containing a single character (letter or number).
As hashcode of these correspond to their ASCII code you get a predictable order that respects the ASCCI order.

Distinct hashcode values ares physically represented by distinct elements of an array in the `HashMap` implementation :

```
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

And  `Iterator` of `HashMap` iterates array elements index by index.
Whereas the result.

Now the ASCII order that the `Map` uses to iterate that looks like a natural order for numeric and alphabetical character is right only for very simple cases **where added `String`s are composed of only 1 letter or 1 digit**.

Add `String`s that contain more than one of character and you would have a unpredictable order  :

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.add("Dad");
mySet.add("Mum");
mySet.add("15454");
mySet.add("90000");

mySet.stream()
     .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " : " + x.hashCode()));

System.out.println(mySet);
```

> 90000 : 54118329
>
> Mum : 77733
>
> 15454 : 46883119
>
> Dad : 68455
>
> [90000, Mum, 15454, Dad]

Comment: don't think `hashcode` is relevant here. For input `D-B-1-E-BX-A-F` op is `1 : 49
A : 65
B : 66
D : 68
E : 69
BX : 2134
F : 70`  and for `D-B-1-E-A-F-BX` op is `1 : 49
A : 65
B : 66
D : 68
E : 69
F : 70
BX : 2134`

Comment: @Shubhendu Pramanik It is relevant here because the OP added String with one character. I added to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The hashCode of Strings of length 1 hash just the sole char, and its hash code is its own numeric value. Voilà, all is ordered.

This phenomenon partly also can be found for Strings with the same prefix, of the same length and is relevant for security exploits. (I believe MD5 needs an artifical seed.)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a coincidence for your testing/working data set which is generating ordered hashes. I have added some more element to your set. Try to run the below code, I think you will get your answer.

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

mySet.add("D");
mySet.add("B");
mySet.add("1");
mySet.add("E");
mySet.add("A");
mySet.add("F");
mySet.add("C");
mySet.add("Z");
mySet.add("M");
mySet.add("Q");


mySet.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Here is my output (which is not in natural order) : 
1
A
Q
B
C
D
E
F
Z
M